# Extracting text between Number and Parantheses in a String field in Excel

Tags: excel, string, text, formula, extract

I have a bunch of values like the one below in a text field in Excel and was wondering if anyone knows a method of extracting the Suburb name (i.e. **Liverpool**) which is usually before the first parantheses and after the last number i.e. postcode (3860 in this case)

PARK RD INT OF QUEENS DR LONDON *3860* **LIVERPOOL** (AGA) VIC

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it always a single word? Also, what have you tried? Can you include the information into your question?

Comment: Not always a single word, for example it could also be Southern Beaches or Lake Como etc.
I have tried MID, RIGHT, LEN but I believe I do not have a good grasp yet on these concepts to solve this problem

Comment: So, `=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-2),MAX(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),0))+2,LEN(A1))`

Comment: Thank you @JvdV this solved it!

Comment: unfortunately it won't. It won't work nomore if there is for example another zero. I'll look into a more precise answer later. Can you let us know what version of Excel you got?

Comment: I have Excel 365

Answer (score 1):

Office 365:

`=LET(a,1+MATCH(1,0/ISNUMBER(0+MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))),b,FIND("(",A1),TRIM(MID(A1,a,b-a)))`

Answer (score 0):

Put your complex value into A1 and try this in B1:

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ";LEFT(A1;FIND(" (";A1)-1)));LEFT(A1;FIND(" (";A1)-1);RIGHT(LEFT(A1;FIND(" (";A1)-1);LEN(LEFT(A1;FIND(" (";A1)-1))-FIND("~";SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1;FIND(" (";A1)-1);" ";"~";LEN(LEFT(A1;FIND(" (";A1)-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1;FIND(" (";A1)-1);" ";""))))))`

This will give you the word before  `(`.
In your example it will return Liverpool.
But fyi: this will work for single words.

Comment: Excel is throwing an error

Comment: It returns LIVERPOOL to me.   What is it saying?

Comment: Maybe the OP's version of Excel uses the comma as argument separator within formulas, not the semicolon as in the formula you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",300)),300))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

You may also try-

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for e.g. 'Milton Keynes'. See OP's comment re the desired extraction not always being a single word.

Comment: Correct @JosWoolley but thank you anyway Harun

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing is best done in steps, to make it easier to understand and modify. That is:

- A1: Text you want to extract from
- B1: Position of first character after the last digit and space =IFERROR(MATCH(10^6, INDEX(--MID(A1, ROW( INDIRECT("1:"& LEN(A1))), 1), )), 0)+2
- C1: Position of opening parenthesis =FIND("(",A1)
- D1: Extract text =MID(A1,C1,D1-C1-1)

This works with multi-word text.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and worked however there is a space at the beginning of every output but I feel that is still manageable

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(J13,LEN(J13)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},J13,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(J13)))),0))),MAX(FIND("(",RIGHT(J13,LEN(J13)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},J13,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(J13)))),0))))-1)),RIGHT(J13,LEN(J13)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},J13,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(J13)))),0))))
```